# ActiveMerchant use Cyber Source flex token for payment

Tags: activemerchant, cybersource

I am implementing Cyber Source with ActiveMerchant. I have the flex token I received when I tokenized the card via [the Cyber Source Documentation](https://developer.cybersource.com/cybs-dev-api-ref/index.html#flex-flex-tokenize-card)

I am then using this token in the `purchase` method of the gateway

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CyberSourceGateway.new(login: 'x', password: 'x')
gateway.purchase(100, 'THETOKEN')
```

However, when I submit this I get the following error in CyberSource:

> the subscription () could not be found

This isn't a subscription payment so I had a look through the code and saw that it does this automatically if the payment method is a string [Github link](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/cyber_source.rb#L730)

Am I doing something wrong in the way I am specifying this token?

[image]

Comment: Is a token/subscription being sent to CyberSource at all? Can you log into the CyberSource business center and tell me what the error is there?

Comment: The error in the business centre is `the subscription () could not be found`. The error is on the actual transaction within the business centre

Comment: I don't know why, but ActiveMerchant is not sending the tokenized card number ( AKA subscription ID) to CyberSource. It is sending a blank or empty string. If you can respond with the request ID returned in the error response I can look into it more from CyberSource side.

Comment: @WillH The request ID is `5786652136026021303011`. Can I assume you work for CyberSource?

Comment: That's what is happening, the subscription ID field is being sent with an empty value.  I don't know ActiveMerchant so can't answer your question, but hopefully that hint will help you. I do work at CyberSource.

Comment: So it could just be a case of removing the section that sends a subscription to CyberSource?

Comment: The subscription ID is required when not sending the credit card number.

Comment: So ActiveMerchant is getting the subscription ID by splitting the token at the semi colon. However the token (from the flex method to tokenize the card) has no semi ccolon...

Comment: None of the CyberSource tokens/subscription ID's have semi colons in them. I'm guessing this is a convention used by ActiveMerchant to pass 2 pieces of data in the same field.